# Проблема с кодом python, отправка сетевых пакетов

Tags: python, сокет

Мне нужно чтобы моя программа бесконечно отправляла сетевые пакеты на свой локальный IP адрес до тех пор пока я не остановлю этот процесс. Но код выдаёт ошибку, помогите пожалуйста

```
import sys
import os
import time
import socket
import random

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bytes = random._urandom(1490)

ip = '192.168.1.62' # Local-IP PC
port = '7854'

os.system("cls")
time.sleep(2)
sent = 1
while True:
     sock.sendto(bytes, (ip,port))
     sent = sent + 1
     port = port + 1
     print("Sent %s packet to %s throught port:%s"%(sent,ip,port))
     if port == 65530:
          port = 1
```

код выводит ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Артём\Desktop\pingPC.py", line 28, in <module>
    sock.sendto(bytes, (ip,port))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: что именно помочь? Перевести ошибку на русский язык? там предельно ясно написано в чем проблема

Comment: перевести то я сам перевёл, я не могу её исправить

Comment: Если в ошибке написано, что требуется целое число, а получена строка, то как это можно исправить?

Comment: я не знаю, если бы я знал я бы сюда не выкладывал, я только начинаю изучать python

Comment: Если тебе скажут, что нужно положить ключи в левый карман, а не в правый, то тоже не будешь знать как исправить?

Comment: как положить ключи я знаю, а вот как поменять тип данных и где именно я понять не могу

Comment: Так в  ошибке указана строка, где возникает ошибка, в ней три параметра. Числом из них может быть только один.

Comment: sock.sendto(bytes, (ip, port)) числовые параметры это айпи и порт

Comment: Ну если получится передать айпи одним целым числом... 

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена следующим образом:

````
import os
import socket
import time
import random
from datetime import datetime

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bytes = random._urandom(1490)

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8080

os.system("cls")
time.sleep(2)
sent = 1
start_time = datetime.now()

while True:
    sock.sendto(bytes, (ip, port))
    port += 1
    if port >= 65535:
        port = 8080
    sent += 1
    print(f"Sent {sent} packets, Time: {datetime.now() - start_time}")```
````